# Create a new dataframe with number of rows based on the months of current dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this input data with the month interval defined by values in 2 columns as such:

```
Customer ID Order quantity  Order valid from    Order valid to
Customer 1  20  Aug-21  Dec-21
Customer 2  50  Oct-21  Jan-22
```

I would like to create a new dataframe where each of the month in the interval is a new row by itself while retaining data on other columns. The output should look like this:

```
Customer    Month   Order quantity
Customer 1  Aug-21  20
Customer 1  Sep-21  20
Customer 1  Oct-21  20
Customer 1  Nov-21  20
Customer 1  Dec-21  20
Customer 2  Oct-21  50
Customer 2  Nov-21  50
Customer 2  Dec-21  50
Customer 2  Jan-22  50
```

Super grateful for any help!

Comment: Please paste your dataframe as text, in the question. Images can't be copy and pasted from...

Comment: pretty much a like for like question of my old one :) - make sure you cast your strings to datetime - `pd.to_datetime(df['Order valid from'],format='%b-%y')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
df = df.assign(Month=df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Order valid from'], x['Order valid to'], freq='M'), axis=1)).explode('Month').drop(['Order valid from', 'Order valid to'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Customer ID  Order quantity      Month
0  Customer 1              20 2021-08-31
1  Customer 1              20 2021-09-30
2  Customer 1              20 2021-10-31
3  Customer 1              20 2021-11-30
4  Customer 2              50 2021-10-31
5  Customer 2              50 2021-11-30
6  Customer 2              50 2021-12-31
```